# how to make dialog box appear on the left?

Tags: android, button, onclick, listeners

I want to add OnclickListener for a button,where in I want to display the Dialog box on the left of the screen on click of it.I tried to implement that but it always appears on the center of the screen.Any idea on how to implement that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly - you want to align your dialog not appear on the center of the screen. Then look at this code sample.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

            if(item == 0) {

            } else if(item == 1) {

            } else if(item == 2) {

            }
        }
    });

     AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
     dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     WindowManager.LayoutParams WMLP = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();


     WMLP.x = 100;   //x position
     WMLP.y = 100;   //y position

     dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(WMLP);

     dialog.show();
```

Here x position's value is pixels from left to right. For y position value is from bottom to top.

Comment: :How can I adjust the size of this dialog box? Say,I want    to make this box look small in size

Comment: @JackDsilva To adjust the size of the dialog you must make a custom layout for the dialog. Good example is shown at http://blog.androgames.net/10/custom-android-dialog/

Comment: Will this cause problems with the position of the dialog depending of the phone used. I had to set WMPL.x to -300 in order to get it to the very begining of the screen?

Answer (score 2):

Before calling `#show()` on your `AlertDialog` you can adjust the gravity of the dialog window:

```
AlertDialog dlg = ...;
dlg.getWindow().getAttributes().gravity = Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
```

This would shift the dialog to the left of the screen. Adjust your gravity flags according to your taste.

Answer (score 0):

Just add following line in your java file and extra space will remove from dialog box.

> Dialog dialog; dialog=new
>   Dialog(Activity.this,android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Panel);

Above code work for me. I hope it will be work for others too. 
Note: You need to pass activity context instead of normal context (getApplicationContext()).