# Please assist i want to make custom dialog left or right align in android

Tags: android, dialog

I need to make my custom dialog left or right align, I have gone through many tutorials but i found that we cannot change the alignment of dialog box. I need to create a dialog in my android similar to the image in below link.

And if it is not possible with the dialog box give some alternate of custom dialog which met my requirements.

[image: here is the layout i want to create that pop up]

Comment: u can use some layout in that position and can make it visible or visibility gone .. I solved my problem like that..if u want I can show my Ui and code..

Comment: sure please send me ur UI n code on vivek19ssb@gmail.com

Comment: you can try this answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607172/how-to-make-dialog-box-appear-on-the-left

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using PopUp Window as dropdown in Android as follows :

```
PopupWindow dropdown_group_popup_window;
View popupView = dropdown_layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.visibility_dropdown_window, 
        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.visibility_dropdown_view));
dropdown_group_popup_window = new PopupWindow(popupView,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
dropdown_group_popup_window.setContentView(popupView); //you can enter your layout here which you wanna show as a dropdown
dropdown_group_popup_window.showAsDropDown(view);      // here you need to pass the view below which you want to show your dropdown
dropdown_group_popup_window.setOutsideTouchable(true);
dropdown_group_popup_window.setTouchable(true);
dropdown_group_popup_window.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
```